# Office365 Single sign on oauth errors

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory, appsource

We are looking for guidance with an error we are seeing in our logs relating to single sign on with Office 365 and our cloud hosted app which allows users to sign in using their Office 365 credentials.

Failed login attempts
Error messages in logs and we get emails O365OAuthCallback
    These always result in a paired of errors in our logs: Error code AADST70002 and AADST70011, Invalid credentials and invalid and the extended message says OAuth doesn’t match reply address.

Our logs show users are able to log in and no customer has ever raised this with our support team.  In spite of many attempts we have never been able to replicate the issue ourselves.

Is this a warning, a rate limit exceeded or a quota exceeded?  What’s the best way to troubleshoot this?  All guidance appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the site is available on two different hostnames? In that case, you need to add both/all of them to the reply addresses in the application registration. That could explain that error. Although, those users would not be able to log in.

Comment: Are you enforcing HTTPS? Is it possible some accessed the page over HTTP?

Comment: @RasmusW I do have both urls in the 'Registered URL' section of the registered app

Comment: @MichelaFederico - Can you please add more information - for example, code snippets showing exactly what are the requests, including the endpoints you are hitting as well as the complete error messages? These two post from Stack Overflow may be helpful to make sure community can help: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).